# ¿Cómo utilizar los Emojis desde el teclado usando unicode?

Tags: html5, email, ascii

No se si han visto últimamente una tendencia de usar emoji en el asunto de los correo, ya varias empresa han comenzado a utilizarlos e incluso **YouTube** usa este tipo de asuntos con emoji en sus notificaciones por correo.

tan solo me gustaría saber como se utilizan.

aqui encontre un monton de los llamados Emojis

### Emojis:

⛄                                                                                                      ⚽ ⚾  ⛳                                                            ⛪      ⛺          ⛲    ⛵                ⛽

### Simbolos:

☂ ☔ ✈ ☀ ☼ ☁ ⚡ ⌁ ☇ ☈ ❄ ❅ ❆ ☃ ☉ ☄ ★ ☆ ☽ ☾ ⌛ ⌚ ⌂ ✆ ☎ ☏ ✉ ☑ ✓ ✔ ⎷ ⍻ ✖ ✗ ✘ ☒ ✕ ☓ ☕ ♿ ✌ ☚ ☛ ☜ ☝ ☞ ☟ ☹ ☺ ☻ ☯ ⚘ ☮ ⚰ ⚱ ⚠ ☠ ☢ ⚔ ⚓ ⎈ ⚒ ⚑ ⚐ ☡ ❂ ⚕ ⚖ ⚗ ✇ ☣ ⚙ ☤ ⚚ ⚛ ⚜ ☥ ✝ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ † ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ✁ ✂ ✃ ✄ ✍ ✎ ✏ ✐  ✑ ✒ ✙ ✚ ✜ ✛ ♰ ♱ ✞ ✟ ✠ ✡ ☸ ✢ ✣ ✤ ✥ ✦ ✧ ✩ ✪ ✫ ✬ ✭ ✮ ✯ ✰ ✲ ✱ ✳ ✴ ✵ ✶ ✷ ✸ ✹ ✺ ✻ ✼ ✽ ✾ ❀ ✿ ❁ ❃ ❇ ❈ ❉ ❊ ❋ ⁕ ☘ ❦ ❧ ☙ ❢ ❣ ♀ ♂ ⚢ ⚣ ⚤ ⚦ ⚧ ⚨ ⚩ ☿ ♁ ⚯ ♛ ♕ ♚ ♔ ♜ ♖ ♝ ♗ ♞ ♘ ♟ ♙ ☗ ☖ ♠ ♣ ♦ ♥ ❤ ❥ ♡ ♢ ♤ ♧ ⚀ ⚁ ⚂ ⚃ ⚄ ⚅ ⚇ ⚆ ⚈ ⚉ ♨ ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬ ♭ ♮ ♯  ⌨ ⏏ ⎗ ⎘ ⎙ ⎚ ⌥ ⎇ ⌘ ⌦ ⌫ ⌧ ♲ ♳ ♴ ♵ ♶ ♷ ♸ ♹ ♺ ♻ ♼ ♽ ⁌ ⁍ ⎌ ⌇ ⌲ ⍝ ⍟ ⍣ ⍤ ⍥ ⍨ ⍩ ⎋ ♃ ♄ ♅ ♆ ♇ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ⏚ ⏛

por ahora la solucion que tengo es copiar y pegar per si me gustaria saber ¿como utilizar los emojis desde el teclado usando unicode?
Gracias

Comment: No tengo claro a que te refieres, que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: Usar el código ascii

Comment: ¿Pero cual es el problema que tienes? ¿no estan siendo leidos bien por algun cliente? ¿No llegan los correos? ¿Que usas para enviarlos? Si pudieras agregar el codigo seria genial

Comment: Lo que necesito es saber como escribir algunos emojis para agregarlos en el asunto de algunos mail que envió, los tres emojis que use arriba lo saque copiando y pegando de unos mail que recibí en mi bandeja de entrada, quiero saber como sacarlo por código o como sea que estos se utilicen

Comment: Puedes sacarlos de aquí http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta pregunta trata sobre ingresar caracters unicode por teclado.

Comment: Yo suelo usar [está web](https://unicode-table.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pues la lista de emojis estandarizados con su respectivo código unicode se puede encontrar  [aquí](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)

Y la lista completa en su versión 4 [aquí](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html). Nótese que hay muchos que no están implementados en todos los clientes, así que es recomendable usar la primera

Comment: Pensaba que dependía de la fuente usada y de si tenían o no esos caracteres definidos

Comment: Unicode está estandarizado y no depende de la fuente, lo que sí depende de la fuente es: **1.** cuál es el diseño del caracter (variaciones en diseño del mismo caracter) y **2.** qué caracteres están implementados y cuáles no... Esto no está relacionado en absoluto con el cliente.